# Why Target required parameter for SQL Trigger?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, triggers, clr

When authoring an INSERT Trigger for SQL Server 2008 Express in C#: I find that the below SqlTrigger annotation is required:

```
[SqlTrigger(Name = "SomeMethod", Target = TABLE_NAME, Event = "INSTEAD OF INSERT")]
public static void SomeMethod() { ... }
```

The Target specification seems like an annoying requirement. I would like to have this trigger available to be run on a variety of tables. Is there anyway to avoid specifying the Target or maybe to override it during creation time in the SQL?

Similar to this question:
[SQL CLR Trigger - get Target / Table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564383/sql-clr-trigger-get-target-table-name)
but I want to be able to dynamically set the Target.

My reason for exploring this, is I have some legacy code that is behaving badly. I want to be able to diagnose a problem potentially in the assembly trigger without shutting it down. Ideally, hijacking the inserts destined for it, doing some diagnostics, then passing back to the original assembly. I believe this Target parameter restricts me from doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`SqlTriggerAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqltriggerattribute.aspx) controls the *registration* of the trigger against a particular table. If you choose to, you can omit this attribute entirely, and perform registrations manually. You can reference the same CLR trigger code for multiple tables, as long as you do the registration [through SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx):

```
CREATE TRIGGER SomeMethod1 ON Table1 AFTER  INSERT AS 
EXTERNAL NAME Namespace.SomeMethod
GO
CREATE TRIGGER SomeMethod2 ON Table2 AFTER  INSERT AS 
EXTERNAL NAME Namespace.SomeMethod
```

`SomeMethod` will then be invoked when inserts are performed against either `Table1` or `Table2`.

---

All of the above being said, however, it's usually a bad sign if your database contains multiple tables with similar enough structure that it even makes sense for the same trigger code to run against all of them. Joe Celko used to refer to this issue as ["Attribute Splitting"](http://www.tdan.com/view-featured-columns/9852) (specifically, Table Splitting).

Comment: I ended up not needing to do this but was considering it as a hack to diagnose a problem with a (seemingly) fixed ODBC connection from a proprietary system. Nice to know it is possible. I never tested the above but seems reasonable. If anyone tests this out please confirm. NG.'s answer appears in contradiction.

Comment: @RyanR. - well, I did try it out before posting, since I wasn't too sure myself beforehand. It certainly works with SQL Server 2012 - I didn't try earlier versions.

Comment: The other thing, about this particular usecase, is I already had a legacy stored procedure defined with a SqlTriggerAttribute. I was trying not to touch this code. I guess I was curious if I could override this attribute in the SQL when it was defined in the C#. My guess is no.

Comment: @RyanR. - You can run the above SQL for an existing CLR trigger (but you'd usually have to have written the trigger to expect to run against different tables)

Comment: "it's usually a bad sign if your database contains multiple tables with similar enough structure" Unless of course you want generic change auditing, especially useful for static data or debugging. (Which the op even stated!)

Answer (score 0):

Since target is a required field in the Attribute, you need to provide it and you can provide it a table name or database name but it can not be altered during run-time. At max what you can do is to stop the execution of the trigger.

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqltriggerattribute.target.aspx